# Py_AtExit registered function not called in gcc optimized compile

Tags: python, gcc

I have a C++ extension module for Python. The module uses pthreads to create multiple compute threads internally. I am registering a finalize() method using Py_AtExit to clean up the threads at exit.

While the unoptmized debug build with g++ works fine, when I build it with -O3, the finalize() method does not get called and Python crashes with various errors (depending on where some compute thread was) including SIGSEGV, SIGABRT and double free corruption.

I initially though the threads were crashing before Python had a chance to call the finalize() function. But 
(1) when I make the finalize() method available to the Python module and explicitly call it at the end of my script, it exits nicely.
(2) I added another function with debug print and registered it to be called at exit. It does not seem to get called even when the script exits nicely either via technique (1) or by restricting the number of threads to 1.
I verified that when the module is compiled in debug mode without optimization flag, the Py_AtExit registered functions do get called at exit.

Anybody experienced this before? I could not find anything in the mailing lists.

Any workaround will be much appreciated.

Comment: I just found a funnier thing: if I register the finalize() function via the atexit module, then it gets called!

Answer (score 0):

This was a C mistake.
Just figured that I was putting it as:

```
assert(Py_AtExit(&finalize) == 0);
```

which was disabled when I was doing the optimized build (the Makefile had -DNDEBUG too, for the optimized build), hence the function was not being called at all.